# python elegant way to iterate over a buffer whose size is not divisible by the step

Tags: python, iterator, buffer

Let's say I have a buffer buf=b"..." of length 953. I want to iterate over it using a step size of 33. Now 953 is not divisible by 33, so there will be a remainder of 29.

I want to iterate over the buffer, but without exceeding the end on the last iteration. I could have used a:

> for index in range(0,954,33): print(index)

The problem is that the last index (924), if assuming the same step size, would exceed the end of the buffer (924+33=957). Now I could use the following:

> for index in range(0,954,33):
> size=min(33,954-index)
> ...

but this is repetitive/verbose and feels unpythonic. I feel like I'm missing a battery here.

The problem with mentioned solutions, is that they work with slices/arrays, bzt not general cases where the indices are passed to functions, where the exact values often matter.

I've created a helper function to avoid repetition. But I wish there was a range variant that explicitly handles remainder cases as part of the standard library

Comment: I don't understand, what are you actually trying to avoid? What is the problem with the last index that you are actually encountering? Consider you wanted to cut up a bytes object, `b = b'01234567'`, then `[b[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(b), 3)]`... does that work for you? Note the `range` that was used

Comment: python >=3.12, [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched)

Comment: Note that slicing does not fail if the "end" index is out of bounds. For example if `a=list(range(10))`, then `a[8:16]` gives `[8, 9]`. So you may not need to bother explicitly calculating `size`.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are that if you are iterating by i steps each time, maybe make it 1 step for now, then in actual loop, conditionally check the size (like subtract the current i index plus the steps you want to take from the size of the buffer) to see if that size would be falsey. Then if it is safe, increment another 32 steps, else increment the remaining amount.

Answer (score 0):

Not short, but simple, i.e. fast:

```
def divide(length, chunk):
    blocks, remainder = divmod(length, chunk)
    index = 0 
    for _ in range(blocks):
        yield index, chunk
        index += chunk
    if remainder:
        yield index, remainder
    
   
for index, size in divide(953, 33):
        print(f"{index=} {size=}")
```

Output:

```
index=0; size=33
index=33; size=33
 --- lines deleted ---
index=891; size=33
index=924; size=29
```